# arduino send logged data over wifi

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on air quality measuring project. it should be able to record gps and air quality data into a SD card and then when wifi is available it should send it to a server. Please help me decide the required hardware for this. 
Can i use ESP8266 module to send this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

- SD card + reader
- GPS module
- Air sensor
- WIFI ESP 8266 should be ok
- Arduino Uno or Mega, depending on if everything fits and calculations to be performed

Start with finding each component, read examples how to use them, than combine them.

Looks like a big project to start with if you are new to Arduino.

Comment: will i be able to send the data when ever a wifi is detected and while the data is being logged ?

Comment: @Yomal If you program it to do that, sure.